# Rotation of a Line Intersecting the Curve $y = x – \log(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: limits, plane-curves

Let a straight line ("line 1") in the $xy$-plane have one end fixed at the origin $(0,0)$, and the other at a variable point $(x, x – \log(x))$ on the curve $y = x – \log(x)$. The domain of $x$ is the positive Real Numbers.

Let $A$ be the angle between line 1 and the positive $x$-axis, then $\tan(A) = (x – \log(x))/x$ which approaches 1 from below as $x \rightarrow \infty$. As $A = \pi/4$ is the only solution of $\tan(A) = 1$ in the positive quadrant, it seems line 1 rotates towards the straight line $y = x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

I do not see any problem so far (although there may be one). My problem comes when I try to picture what is happening.

The gap between the curve $y = x – \log(x)$ and the straight line $y = x$, is $\log(x)$ which increases as $x$ increases. It therefore seems line 1 should be rotating away from the straight line $y = x$ instead of towards it.

These conclusions are contradictory. I would appreciate any help in pointing out where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not contradictory. This means that your intuition (the second argument) is wrong.

Let's denote $f(x)=x-\ln(x)$, $O$ the origin, $B(x,x)$ a point on the line $y=x$, $C(x,f(x))$ a point on the curve $y=f(x)$, and $P(x,0)$ on the $x$-axis.

Your question is: why the angle $\theta(x)=\angle BOC$ isn't diverging to $-\infty$ when the distance $BC$ tends to $\infty$?

That happens because the distance $OP$ is increasing way faster than the distance $BC$?

A clearer situation is when $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$. Clearly, the distance $BC$ tends to $\infty$, but the angle $\theta(x)$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will need to think about it. Note in my question I was not asking about the divergence of the angle BOC. I was asking about the direction angle COP changes as x increases. Your example,  $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$, shows the angle COP could be independent of increasing separation from the straight line $y=x$ but I am asking about changes in angle COP when there is a dependence on separation.

Comment: The angle BOP being constant, knowing about the variations of COP is equivalent to know the variations of BOC. Since the question was involving BC, I was hoping that speaking about BOC gives a clearer picture.